# Cannot resolve symbol "tensorflow" flutter framework

Tags: java, android, flutter, tensorflow-lite

I get an error while trying to import TensorFlow lite from a maven repository on a flutter framework

Error: Cannot resolve symbol "tensorflow"

Specifically, I would like to use tflite Interpreter hence the import 
MainActivity.java file as below

```
package Doesnt.matter;

import org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter;

import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.lang.Integer;
import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.Result;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.MappedByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);
  } 

}
```

app level build.gradle file :

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    //throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress "lite"
        noCompress "tflite"
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "Doesnt.Matter"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:24.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-image-label-model:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-face-model:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-model-interpreter:22.0.1'

    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:2.0.0'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

android build.gradle file

```
group 'Doesnt.Matter'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://google.bintray.com/tensorflow'
        }
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                details.useVersion "26.1.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I resolve the dependency and be able to use tflite and ML models.

The maven repo url : https://google.bintray.com/tensorflow

It is functional and has files in it, so no problem there.

Am I failing to include anything specific

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

### **Android SDK version**

1. You are required to use min SDK level 24
2. Go to File/Project Structure/Modules
3. Scroll down and find $var[something...]
4. now replace it with 24 sync and recompile